# Cookie Injector for Opera browser?

Tags: firefox, browser, opera, cookies

I'm looking for the best add-on to cookie-injection for Opera.

I'm tired of having to use Grease monkey on Firefox, I want to inject in my main browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do this from the properties file using

```
opera:config#UserAgent
```

or

```
opera:config#SpoofUserAgentID
```

See the [docs](http://www.opera.com/support/usingopera/operaini/#ua).